# Wrap entire span on new line if doesn't fit

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have two child divs 20% and 80%. The last one contains nested `span`s and in case of text doesn't fit on the same line it is moved on the next line by single word (default behavior).

HTML:

```
<div class="post-short-footer">
   <div class="read-more-post"></div>
   <div class="post-short-meta-container">
      <span class="posted-on"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true">Some text</i></span>
      <span class="cat-links"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Some text</span>
      <span class="comments-link"><i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.post-short-footer {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.read-more-post {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;    
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0.6em 0.6em;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #3b9be5;
}
.post-short-meta-container {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 1em;
    width: 80%;
    line-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
```

But I need to achieve next result if text in span doesn't fit the line move whole span to the next line.

I already tried:

```
.post-short-meta-container span {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This doesn't move text to the next line instead it makes first `div` smaller in order to get free space for text and this is not desirable behavior.

[image]
[image]

And I want to achieve:

[image]

Is it possible to get such result using only CSS?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `<span>` tag is inline by default, so the text inside will break when wrapping happens. You can set it to `display: inline-block` so that it renders as a whole block also remains inline level. Note, wrapping may still happen but only if the text length exceeds the parent container.

```
.post-short-meta-container span {
  ...
  display: inline-block;
}
```

> `display: inline-block` The element generates a block element box that will be flowed with surrounding content as if it were a single inline box (behaving much like a replaced element would) - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

And for the layout you're trying to achieve, you can wrap the text "Read more" into a `<a>` tag, and set the button link style on it instead of the table cell, see the updated demo below.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7cc2eLc2/)**

```css
.post-short-footer {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.read-more-post {
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}
.read-more-post a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #3b9be5;
  padding: 0.6em 0.6em;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  display: block;
}
.post-short-meta-container {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 1em;
  width: 80%;
  line-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
.post-short-meta-container span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.3em;
  margin: 0.3em;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-short-footer">
  <div class="read-more-post">
    <a href="#">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="post-short-meta-container">
    <span>Some text here</span>
    <span>Some text here</span>
    <span>Some text here</span>
    <span>Some text here</span>
    <span>Some text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may notice given the same `margin` but the left/right spacing and top/bottom spacing is not the same in the example, follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/483779) if you need it to be pixel perfect.

**UPDATE**

There is a better way to do it, that is CSS3 [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox), check out the snippet below.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cfrmhx33/)**

```css
.post-short-footer {
  display: flex;
}

.read-more-post {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.read-more-post a {
  border: 1px solid #3b9be5;
  padding: 0.6em 0.6em;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.post-short-meta-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.post-short-meta-container span {
  padding: 0.3em;
  margin: 0.3em;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-short-footer">
  <div class="read-more-post">
    <a href="#">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="post-short-meta-container">
    <span>Some text here</span>
    <span>Some text here</span>
    <span>Some text here</span>
    <span>Some text here</span>
    <span>Some text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
.post-short-meta-container > span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

An `inline-block` element is a unit that always remains a block (but within the text flow), which can only be moved as a whole and not be divided.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `display: table`, and the behavior of resizing your divs are because of that.
I would advise to change your display to `inline-block` as said on the answer above and vertical aligning it through `line-height`