# How to wrap element in CSS not the word

Tags: html, css

I have a list of `span` elements in a `td` with a fixed width.

I want to wrap the span elements, but no the words within the span elements.

So if I have

```
<td>
    <span>bind</span>
    <span>defaults</span>
    <span>nofail</span>
    <span>x-systemd.requires=zfs-mount.service</span>
    <span>bind</span>
    <span>defaults</span>
    <span>nofail</span>
    <span>x-systemd.requires=zfs-mount.service</span>
</td>
```

I want each `span` to go to a new line if needed, but not break the span in the middle.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056482/wrap-entire-span-on-new-line-if-doesnt-fit

Answer (score 1):

Set your spans to be `display:inline-block`

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>bind</span>
      <span>defaults</span>
      <span>nofail</span>
      <span>x-systemd.requires=zfs-mount.service</span>
      <span>bind</span>
      <span>defaults</span>
      <span>nofail</span>
      <span>x-systemd.requires=zfs-mount.service</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep the spans from breaking on the text, add `white-space: nowrap;` to the rules for your span.

Answer (score 0):

white-space: nowrap;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Try this out. I've posted the mozilla link as well.